# XAML Hot Reload for IOS Device not starting on Windows or MacBook Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project that I am opening in an IOS Simulator. My Windows 10 PC is connected on the same network to my MacBook. But after the IOS Simulator shows up this message appears in the Debug Console:

> [HotReload] (2020-05-30 01:00:03.2): INFO: XAML Hot Reload encountered a problem and failed to start. Use Help -> Report a Problem if the issues persists.
>   [HotReload] (2020-05-30 01:00:03.2): INFO: Stopping All Hot Reload sessions due to Failed ...
>   [HotReload] (2020-05-30 01:00:03.2): INFO: (Xamarin Testing.iOS) Stopped Hot Reload session due to Failed ...
>   [HotReload] (2020-05-30 01:00:03.2): INFO: Stopped Hot Reload session.

I have tried running Hot Reload on just the Mac to no avail. Additionally, all the setup should be right, as I've double-checked all the correct options are ticked.

Does anyone know why the Hot Reloader isn't running?

Comment: If you are sure that you have set up everything correctly, then it is clear what is left to be done. It's in the message - "`Use Help -> Report a Problem` if the issues persists."

Comment: Are you using your Linker Behavior setting "Don't link"?
Ensure rebuild the solution after this update.

Comment: @MihailDuchev Yeah ill be doing that next, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious...

Comment: @FilipePilettiPlucenio Yeah, I did set that already.

Comment: Check the logs in Visual Studio>Help>Xamarin>Zip Logs.

Comment: @Minirobbo Hi ,welcome to SO ! Whether the version of VS is the newest? In addition , have a check with [Troubleshooting XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019) .Maybe there will be the solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS version 12 seems to not work with hot reload. I now just use IOS version 13 and Xamarin.Forms NuGet package version > 4.5.0.356

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO !

**First** , have a check with **Tools -> Options... -> Xmarin ->Hot Reload -> Enable ...**

[image]

**Second** , you need to check whether `Xaml` code contains error when debugging .

Comment: Yeah this was all correct. I found i can just use the XAML previewer (which wasnt previously working) as long as i downgraded the xamarin.forms NuGet package to version 4.5.0.356. Ik this sort of defeats the point of hot reload, but i cant get it to work so this is my alternative

Comment: @Minirobbo Okey ,whether it occurs in an new created project ?

Comment: I tried this with ios version 13 and it seems to work... possibly a problem with IOS version 12 then. :|